# Why does this subgradient identity hold?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

(This is adapted from the paper [Scenarios and Policy Aggregation in Optimization Under Uncertainty](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~rtr/papers/rtr120-ScenariosAggregation.pdf) by Rockafellar and Wets)

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be a convex function, and let $\mathcal{C}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ be closed and convex. Define the function $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ by 
$$\varphi(U,V)=F(U+V)+\delta_\mathcal{C}(U+V),$$
where $\delta_\mathcal{C}$ is the indicator function on $\mathcal{C}$ (i.e. $\delta_\mathcal{C}(X)=+\infty$ if $X\not\in\mathcal{C}$ and $0$ otherwise).

Equation (5.15) in the linked paper asserts that
$$ (Y,-\bar{W})\in\partial\varphi(V,U)\Leftrightarrow Y-\bar{W}\in\partial(F+\delta_\mathcal{C})(X)\text{ where }X=U+V. $$
Why is this true? I know that the subdifferential is a closed convex set, so I would expect that, say the midpoint $\tfrac{1}{2}(Y-\bar{W})$ would lie in the subdifferential, but not the sum...

Am I missing something? I suspect this may be connected to Minty's theorem but I can't quite see it.

Comment: Try a small example, such as $f(x)=x^2$ and $\mathcal{C}=\mathbb{R}$. The left hand side of (5.15) is $Y=-W=2(U+V)$ while the right hand side is $Y-W = 2(U+V)$. These statements are not equivalent, so the statement is not true.

Comment: @LinAlg Thanks for your comment--that would throw a wrench into the main convergence proof in the paper. Maybe you can expand your comment into an answer?

Comment: @LinAlg Not true. The left-hand side of (5.15) is $(Y,-W)=2(U,V)$ in your example.

Comment: @daw my calculus may be a bit rusty, but don't we have $\varphi(U,V) = (U+V)^2$, so $\partial\varphi(U,V) = (2(U+V), 2(U+V))$, so the left hand side is $(Y,-\bar{W}) = (2(U+V), 2(U+V))$?

Comment: @LinAlg true, but the paper deals with the situation that $u$ and $v$ live in subspaces that are orthogonal to each other. The subgradients are subsets of these spaces as well, so the $v$-component of the $u$-subgradient disappears

Comment: @daw that is an important detail, thank you for spotting it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per definition in that paper $\phi : N \times N^\perp\to \mathbb R$, $f:X\to \mathbb R$, $X=N \oplus N^T$.
Assume $\phi(u,v) = f(u+v)$, and $f(x) = \phi(Kx,Jx)$, where $J,K$ are orthogonal projectors onto a subspace $N$ and its complement $N^\perp$.

Note that the subdifferentials $\partial \phi$ and $\partial f$ are subsets of two different vector spaces. The first is a subset of $N\times N^\perp \subset X\times X$, while the latter is a subset of $X$.

Let $(y,-w) \in \partial \phi(u,v)\subset N\times N^\perp$. Then
$$
\langle y, a \rangle - \langle w,b\rangle \le \phi(u+a,v+b)-\phi(u,v)
= f( u+v +a+b) - f(u+v) \quad \forall a\in N,b\in N^\perp.
$$
Due to the orthogonality relations, we get
$$
\langle y-w, a+b\rangle \le f( u+v +a+b) - f(u+v) \quad \forall a\in N,b\in N^\perp.
$$
Clearly $y-w\in \partial f(u+v)$.

Now let $y\in N$, $w\in N^\perp$ be given such that $y-w\in \partial f(x)$. Define
$u:=Kx$, $v:=Jx$. Now we can reverse the above reasoning to obtain $(y,-w) \in \partial \phi(u,v)\subset N\times N^\perp$.